# How to view a character with glyphshow?

Tags: postscript

```
/Helvetica findfont setfont
/a glyphshow
```

The interpreter give out a nocurrentpoint error. How to show a character with glyphshow in PostScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indicate *where* to put it. (This is the meaning of the "nocurrentpoint" error.)

Oh, you'll also need to scale the font before setting it. The default font size is 1pt (1/72 inch) [very small]. (Not an *error* per se, but a foreseeable obstacle in your path.)

As pipitas (our SO Postscript top-dog) recommends, here's a complete example:

```
%!
/Helvetica findfont 24 scalefont setfont   %or: /Helvetica 24 selectfont
306 396 moveto    %move to center of 8.5x11 page
/a glyphshow
showpage
```

Comment: To make it fully clear: `/Helvetica findfont 24 scalefont setfont 306 396 moveto /a glyphshow` should do it.

Comment: @pipitas Thanks. It looks much better fleshed-out. ... Looks like Ken just took your Postscript crown! You're still top in `gs`, tho.

Comment: Hehe. I'll happily hand over the GS crown too. KenS has just to keep contributing, and I'll keep upvoting him  :-)  -- It's good to see GS developers participating here...