# How to set character encoding in postscript?

Tags: postscript

The goal is to make this line work properly:

```
(árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép,ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP) show
```

All of these characters are in **CE Encoding Vector**.

These links may help find the answer:

- [Umlauts in PostScript](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/378009)
- [Printing Swedish Character set with PS](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2357276#2357276)
- [how to set up the Encoding Vector for OS/2](http://computer-programming-forum.com/36-postscript/f76ce49039820cee.htm)

[This - glyphshow -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570533/how-to-view-a-character-with-glyphshow)  using [this character-table](http://www.jdawiseman.com/papers/trivia/character-entities.html) method works, but I think it will be better if I could change the character set/encoding vector.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend John Deubert's Acumen Journal.

http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html

I'd suggest you look at November/December 2001.